# How do I separate a currency symbol from a money value and preserve decimals and commas?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take the output of `toLocaleString` and do a little extra formatting on it.  I started with this code:

```
displayAmount = 1234.56789
currencyFormatted = displayAmount.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});
```

The value of currencyFormatted becomes:

```
$1,234.57
```

Not bad, but for various reasons, I want to be able to add a space between the `$` and the `1`, and wrap a span around it. So the desired output is:

```
<span>$</span> 1,234.57
```

So I added this code, which I derived from [other answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370293/184108):

```
symbolSeparated = currencyFormatted.split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean);
myElement.innerHTML = "<span>" + symbolSeparated[0] + "</span> " + symbolSeparated[1];
```

But, I got:

```
<span>$</span> 1
```

I realized that my split was considering commas and decimals as text, and splitting there. I tried some other regex that I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26706783/184108), like `/[^0-9\.]+/g`, but it mostly seemed to just fail and `symbolSeparated[1]` would be undefined.

In any case, it doesn't have to be regex, it can be any combination of functions or whatever. The question is, **how can I separate the currency symbol from the numerical value, while preserving decimals and commas?**

Please note, the currency symbol is *not* guaranteed to be one character in length (otherwise I could just use `substring()`). It can be from 1 to 3 characters, so far as I know.

Also, answers not dependant on jQuery are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. The regular expression `/^(\D*)(.*)/` looks for all non-digit characters at the front of the string and saves it in the first matching group and then puts the remainder of the string in the second matching group.

```
const regex = /^(\D*)(.*)/;

function x() {
    displayAmount = 1234.56789
    currencyFormatted = displayAmount.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});


    m = regex.exec(currencyFormatted );
    myElement.innerHTML = "<span>" + m[1] + "</span> " + m[2];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The result I'm getting, though, is `<span>$1234.57</span> $`. I'm not sure why the dollar sign is repeated, but in any case, is that regex definitely correct?

Comment: The regex itself is fine. I just used the wrong indexes when accessing the matching groups. I have corrected my answer. The correct line is myElement.innerHTML = "<span>" + m[1] + "</span> " + m[2];

Comment: Works great now, thank you! Just so I'm clear, `m[0]` will be a complete duplicate of the originally provided string?

Comment: `m[0]`  will be the full match which in this case the full string. If you had a regex that only matched a portion of the original string them `m[0]` would only be the substring that was matched.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, using `String.replace`:

```
myElement.innerHTML = displayAmount.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).replace(/^(\D*)(.*)/, '<span>$1</span> $2')
```